# pandas: plot .value_counts() of same column from two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two dataframes with same columns (different values, important for me not to combine the two).

I would like to make a bar plot of the `.value_counts()` of the same column for these dataframes (e.g. column 'A' in dataframe1 will be green, and column 'A' in dataframe2 will be blue).

of course also important that the X axis values will be compared correctly (that is, each X label will show value_counts of val1 for both, then val2 etc.).

for now I can only do it seperately for each, for example:
`df1['A'].value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind='bar',title='col A distribution dataframe1')`

It is not vital for me to do it in one line (can also use "native" matplotlib).

Comment: Can you please add your DataFrames? As a first guess I would join the two columns in one DataFrame and plot the new DataFrame as a bar plot.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and try to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the DataFrames together and when you plot from them, pandas will automatically put the bars side by side. Just make sure, before you plot, you add a suffix/prefix to your 2nd DataFrame's column that you're going to plot so the legend won't be confusing.

```py
repeating_columns = #repeating columns that you aren't going to plot

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).drop([repeating_columns], axis=1)
df[['df1_A','df2_A']].plot(kind='bar')
```